# What is the O complexity of the number of "empty" nodes in an AVL tree?

Tags: heap, complexity-theory, avl-tree

We know that an AVL tree is usually very close to being balanced. Let's say we take an AVL tree and put it into an array (very similar to a heap, where the parent is index i, left child is 2i, and right child is 2i+1), how many empty indices would you get in terms of big O complexity?

So I know that the minimum number of nodes in a tree of height h = Fibonacci(h+2) - 1. So number of empty indices = 2^h - 1 - (Fibonacci(h+2) - 1) = 2^h - Fibonacci(h+2). But I don't know what to do next to prove it's complexity. I think it's O(log(n)), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Look at the closed form of Fibonacci formulae. It seems that `2^n = Omega(Fib(n))`, therefore `O(2^h-Fib(h+2))=O(2^h)`

Answer (score 0):

If `h` is 0-based (as is the usual convention), the minimum number of nodes in an AVL tree with height `h` is `F(h+3) - 1`.

Let `n = F(h+3) - 1` and let's try to solve for `h` to find the maximum height of an AVL tree with `n` nodes.

The closed form for F(x) is given by Binet's formula (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) for details):

```
F(x) = (phi^n - psi^n)/sqrt(5)
```

Therefore,

```
n = (phi^(h+3) - psi^(h+3))/sqrt(5) - 1
 >= (phi^(h+3) - 1)/sqrt(5) - 1 since |psi| < 1
```

Solving for `h` yields

```
h <= log_phi(sqrt(5)(n + 1) + 1) - 3
  <= 1.4405 log2(n)
```

A full tree with height `h` has `2^(h+1) - 1` nodes. Or in terms of `n`:

```
   2^(h+1) - 1
<= 2^(1.4405 log2(n) + 1) - 1
 = 2 * (2^log(n))^1.4405 - 1
 = 2n^1.4405 - 1
```

Hence the number of empty nodes is bounded by

```
2n^1.4405 - 1 - n = O(n^1.4405)
```